# two spiring balances

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

My 9th grade textbook says when we set a apparatus by the following procedure "tie the free end of two spring balances X and Y together and name this intersection A and then fix the rigid end of spring balance X to a wall and name this point B and name the rigid end of spring balance Y as C" , and then pull C towards ourselves , we will be exerting a force f on X at point A and the same force will be exerted at the same point by Y on A. so the readings on both the spring balances , would individually equal the force that we originally applied

well , that is what the book says after all , and i think that when we are pulling the rigid of balance Y towards ourselves the force just gets distributed in the spring , and the reading on each of the spring balances is not the force that we applied but the readings on both the spring balances added together equals the force that we applied. This is because the spring is now a single system and not a body composed of two different systems

- Am i right ?
- if not please tell me where and why i am wrong ?

Comment: Your book is right. The force you applied is same throughout the system. It doesn't get distributed so that half of the force is on one balance and half is on other. A car has all its parts undergoing same change when forced.

Comment: well , thanks , i just needed a confirmation
basically what is happening , is that  one balance when exerts a force on another at the point of intersection , there is a corresponding force on the balance that applies the force, and thus the balances balance their forces and remain in a stable state ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am providing the following response because I feel you are not understanding the physics involved of this problem.

First, replace the scales with a cable.  You pull on point C and the force is felt at point B. Since point B does not move, this means the wall is providing **an equal and opposing** force.
Next, replace the cable with the scales. Once point A is stable, the force displayed on both scales will be the same as the force applied at point C, but they **oppose each other, so they cancel**. The only effect of the scales is to measure and transmit the applied force (form point C) to the wall (point B).