# Does energy transmission depend on the speed of incoming particle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

Since a few past days , I am struggling with finding an in depth atomic model of force exchange between colliding paricles (originally newtons third law) , because at this point of time i am unable to understand any least bit of quantum field theory or quantum electrodynamics , because its covered in a lot of math and i am not ready for that (i am currently in intermediate stages of high school ).

Because everything that commonly exchanges forces on earth is made of atoms , imagine two of them , with an atom **A moving** towards B and another atom **B stationary**.

Now there are are exactly three different combinations in which this collision can take place

- A and B are of equal masses.
- A is more massive than B.
- A is less massive than B.

---

```
                         # A and B are of equal masses #
```

During the developing of the model , i considered only the first case mentioned above .

The first thing "i feel so i want to state" is that, these atoms will not exert a considerable force on one another , until  the moving atom is a specific distance from the stationary atom . Considering this as an assumption , as such a distance can be thought of anywhere in space , so dont think about it much. Coming back to the original scenario consider some position of **B** with respect to **A** ,such that there is no force acting on both atoms at this position but **A's** moving any smallest amount of displacement would result in a force applied on both the atoms , with the forces opposite in direction . So , let this displacement be **X** and the position of **A** after covering this **X** be **P** . At this point **P** , **A**  must exert an force on **B** as well as should **B** apply the same force on **A** . If these both forces are exerted simultaneously , then newtons third law is correct , but if velocity of **A** decreases first by force of **b** and only after that **A's**  accelerates B then , there would be an extra force being exerted on **A** as **B** starts to feel the force of "B" . But this must be incorrect for newtons third law to hold true . 
So I came up with this explanation for the simultaniety of this , as i could not find any on the internet , or maybe i could not understand any ;

The force that **A** , whether it may be an EM wave or something else , takes a time to emerge from its source , but velocity is continuous , i mean EM waves take some time Z to emerge from the nucleus but **A** will be still moving during this time . So as i already mentioned this point **P** , this point will be reached by the atom in the same time **Z** . So after **A** reaches **p** , the EM wave / waves will be released and they exactly apply a force on both atoms that it will create a velocity **v** in both the atoms in opposite directions , so that atom **A** who earlier had velocity **v** will come to an halt and **B** will start moving with velocity **v** .

---

```
                  ## A is more massive than B ##
```

For explaining this i just needed the fact that bigger masses have stronger EM waves at every point in space , probably because of concentrated EM waves at every point in space. This would lead to the fact that as soon as atom **A** reaches the aforementioned point **P** there would be an great acceleration in 
atom **B** but little retardation in **A**.

---

```
                  ##A is less massive than B.##
```

Well this one could be also explained by a similar reasoning like above.

---

SO is this model right ? 
if yes , please help me with the mathametics ?
if not please suggest an alternative ?

Comment: Wow - you are making this very confusing for yourself and your readers. First - remove the three different cases; they are irrelevant to the underlying concepts. Second - you are really asking "when two atoms approach each other, there will come a point where they first 'become aware' of the presence of the other. How is the force between them arrived at such that they each feel the effect at the same time?" . Right? If you could greatly simplify your question you are more likely to get a proper answer...

Comment: i did that but did not work 
however , a you are right about my doubts , they are some of those doubts that i had before developing this model


http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231896/conservation-of-momentum?noredirect=1#comment505206_231896

http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231846/two-spiring-balances?noredirect=1#comment504783_231846

http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231432/newtons-third-law-at-the-quantum-level/231502?noredirect=1#comment504107_231502

http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231494/atomic-collisions?noredirect=1#comment503830_231494

Comment: You have hit analysis paralysis by overthinking it. Step back - do you understand something like Rutherford scattering? Note that the potential for Rutherford scattering is the long range electrostatic (or gravitational, or any other $1/r^{2}$) potential. The path to analyzing it is straightforward, and written up more than a century ago. Your three mass combinations fall naturally out of the solution. Another place to start is hard sphere collisions. Note that here, there actually is a difference between the classic and quantum solutions, so that will help you see the differences.